# How to define Typescript types for a form that can be used for edit or create

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, zod

I'm using Formik to handle a form that I'd like to reuse for both edit and create. The input is a single string. When I create a new name, the API only takes `{ name: string }`, however when it's an edit the API takes `{ name: string, id: string }`. I created a discriminated union to distinguish the types in each case:

```
type NameInputProps =
  | {
      action: `edit`;
      id: string; // If it's an edit also require an ID
      isLoading: boolean;
      isOpen: boolean;
      name: string;
      onClose: () => void;
      onSubmit: (values: ApiNameEditInput) => Promise<void>;
    }
  | {
      action: `create`;
      isLoading: boolean;
      isOpen: boolean;
      name: string;
      onClose: () => void;
      onSubmit: (values: ApiNameCreateInput) => Promise<void>;
    };
```

`ApiNameEditInput` is `{ name: string; id: string}` and `ApiNameCreateInput` is `{ name: string }`.

This is the first part of the modal:

```
export const NameInputModal = (props: NameInputProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { action, isLoading, isOpen, name, onClose, onSubmit } = props;

  let formikParams;

  if (action === `edit`) {
    formikParams = {
      initialValues: {
        name,
        id: props.id,
      },
      onSubmit,
      validationSchema: toFormikValidationSchema(ApiNameEditInputSchema),
    };
  } else {
    formikParams = {
      initialValues: {
        name,
      },
      onSubmit,
      validationSchema: toFormikValidationSchema(ApiNameCreateInputSchema),
    };
  }

  const formik = useFormik(formikParams); // <-- TS error here

  // Modal continues below...
```

Just as a note, `ApiNameEditInputSchema` and `ApiNameEditInputSchema` are Zod schemas, but I don't believe these are relevant to the problem.

The TS error I'm getting is:

```
        Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
          Type '{ name: string; date: string; holidayId: string; } | { name: string; date: string; holidayId?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; date: string; holidayId: string; }'.
            Type '{ name: string; date: string; holidayId?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; date: string; holidayId: string; }'.
              Types of property 'holidayId' are incompatible.
```

The issue might be with the `onSubmit` functions and possibly the validation, however the function input types are derived from the Zod schemas, as:

```
type ApiNameEditInput = z.infer<typeof ApiNameEditInputSchema>;
```

Here is a CodeSandbox with a working example of the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-yalow-kl43wb?file=/src/App.tsx

Any pointer on what's happening here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: Is the issue that you're using `ApiNameEditInputSchema` in the else block? Since the else block should be for creation, I'd expect that this line `validationSchema: toFormikValidationSchema(ApiNameEditInputSchema)` would instead use `ApiNameCreateInputSchema`

Comment: @cstoltze Sorry that was a copy/paste error when simplifying the code for SO. I've checked and my real code is using the right schema and showing the TS error.

Comment: @vr. Added a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-yalow-kl43wb?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Sometimes it’s easier to use the dumbest solution, which is that the id is always present and it’s an empty string if not provided.  Dealing with unions on callback function can be a nightmare.